# Rest api HAL and structured response body with nested reference

Tags: rest, hateoas

How would you approach this case? In this example an address in is only nested in structure, it does not exist e as separated resource so I am not using _embedded. 
Should be the link to country in top root _links element or is it possible or correct to have one more _links object nested in "address" substructure?

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"Company X",
   "address":{ 
      "countryId":54,
      "city":"Prague",
      "zip":"11000"
   },
   "_links":{ 
      "self":{ 
         "href":"http://user-management/organisations/1"
      },
      "country":{ 
         "href":"http://user-management/countries/54"
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks,

Lukas

Answer (score 0):

As per HAL specification , **Links must be contained directly within a resource**

Hence , if address is not a resource then it must not contain links but root resource can contain link to country as mentioned in your example.

for more details  [click here [HAL Specification]](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) and go to Links sections